# Model Binder - how to make optional

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

i wish to make the property **DateOfBirth** optional in relation to the model binder

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    public int MP_CustomerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]     
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true, ErrorMessage="This is the error message")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public int NoOfVehicles { get; set; }
}
```

i have tried removing the attribute all together, but it still classes it as required.

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make it nullable

```
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```